# pygame.error: video system not initialized. pygame.init() already called

Tags: python, pygame

This is pretty much the simplest code you can make in pygame. All it does is create a window and allow you to close it. However, I am getting this error
pygame.error: video system not initialized. I searched online for this and it seems most people forget to call pygame.init(). I am not sure why I am getting this error.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,500))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `sys.exit(0)` and the end and you are done

Here is some info from official document

> pygame.quit() uninitialize all pygame modules quit() -> None
>   Uninitialize all pygame modules that have previously been initialized.
>   When the Python interpreter shuts down, this method is called
>   regardless, so your program should not need it, except when it wants
>   to terminate its pygame resources and continue. It is safe to call
>   this function more than once: repeated calls have no effect.
>
> Note, that pygame.quit()uninitialize all pygame modules will not exit
>   your program. Consider letting your program end in the same way a
>   normal python program will end.

here is a sample code for you.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500 ) )


while True :
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: When I tried your code, pygame crashed. It works if I take what you wrote and add pygame.quit() on the next line

Comment: updated the code for you, please try this code and see if it works as it is . and also check this official test case of pygame for more info . https://gist.github.com/MarquisLP/b534c95e4a11efaf376e