# pygame.error:video system not initialized but I already used pygame.init()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, init

I checked the question with the same error as myself, but it was an initialization problem. So I made sure I did the initialization
I used pygame.init() but error occured.I do not understand this.
so I specify where Pycharm IDE tells me it is in the code below. help me

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK=(0,0,0)
pad_width=480
pad_height=640
fight_width=36
fight_height=38
enemy_width=26
enemy_height=20
def drawObject(obj,x,y):
    global gamepad
    gamepad.blit(obj,(x,y))
def runGame():
    global gamepad,clock,fighter,enemy
    x=pad_width*0.45
    y=pad_height*0.9
    x_change=0
    enemy_x=random.randrange(0,pad_width-enemy_width)
    enemy_y=0
    enemy_speed=3
    ongame=False
    while not ongame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():      #I got an error here
            if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
                ongame=True
            if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change-=5
                elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change+=5
            if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT or event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change=0
        gamepad.fill(BLACK)

        x+=x_change
        if x<0:
            x=0
        elif x>pad_width-fight_width:
            x=pad_width-fight_width

        drawObject(fighter,x,y)
        enemy_y+=enemy_speed
        if enemy_y>pad_height:
            enemy_y=0
            enemy_x=random.randrange(0,pad_width-enemy_width)

        drawObject(enemy,enemy_x,enemy_y)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()

def initGame():
    global gamepad,clock ,fighter,enemy

    pygame.init()
    gamepad=pygame.display.set_mode((pad_width,pad_height))
    fighter=pygame.image.load('fighter.png')
    enemy=pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()

initGame()
runGame()  #and here
```

Comment: This can help you out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49845387/pygame-error-video-system-not-initialized-pygame-init-already-called?rq=1

Comment: As stated in the comment above, when I added that sys.exit(0), the error does not appear, but it turns off as soon as it is executed.

Comment: I don't know why the code in this link works fine (source code in the book) and my code doesn't work as long as I followed the book.https://github.com/SuperGeniusAn/Practice_Python/blob/main/PygamePractice3

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the indentation of the `pygame.quit()` making it part of the `while not ongame:` loop.

So the code correctly initialises PyGame, but then at the end of the first iteration through the main loop, that final `pygame.quit()` shuts everything down - making the event system un-initialised and resulting in the error message you're seeing.

Adjusting the indentation is enough to fix it:

```
def runGame():
    global gamepad,clock,fighter,enemy
    x=pad_width*0.45
    y=pad_height*0.9
    x_change=0
    enemy_x=random.randrange(0,pad_width-enemy_width)
    enemy_y=0
    enemy_speed=3
    ongame=False
    while not ongame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():      #I got an error here
            if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
                ongame=True

        # [ ... ]
                
        drawObject(enemy,enemy_x,enemy_y)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()    # <<-- HERE (un-indent 1 place)
```

So while it *is* just a typo, it's also a common enough situation to warrant a full answer.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't solve it, but it was solved thanks